# Base class is added to Subclass with tablePerHiearchy false on SQL Created with Grails 2.3.2 and Hibernate 3.6.10.3 after Migrating from Grails 1.3.7

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I currently have this for my Base class:

```
abstract class NSSDomainEntity {

    String id
    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
}
```

Then my class:

```
class NSSPermissions extends NSSDomainEntity {

    static mapping = {
         table name: 'ncm_permissions', schema: 'NSSPROD'
         id generator: 'uuid'
    }
}
```

Somehow upon running the app the generated sql was:

`select this_.id as id40_0_, this_1_.version as version40_0_ from ncm_permissions this_, nssdomain_entity this_1_`

The Base class was also used to query giving me an exception

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Is tablePerHiearchy no longer supported in grails 2.3.2?

Or would there be any settings that I have missed. The setup was still working as per grails 1.3.7 before upgrading to 2.3.2.

Comment: Does the `ncm_permissions` table exist?

Comment: Not related to your question directly but it is unusual to be updating to 2.3.2 at this point.  We released 2.3.2 about 7 years ago.  If you want to use Grails 2 for some reason, is there a reason you picked that particular patch release?

Answer (score 0):

> Is tablePerHiearchy no longer supported in grails 2.3.2?

I believe that it is.